# Start sphinx toctree numbering at zero

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a sphinx reST file and a toctree defined like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :numbered:

   01.rst
   02.rst
```

The files 01.rst and 02.rst then look like this:

```
First file
==========

foobaz bar
```

and the sections in the HTML are numbered starting from 1.

However, I want to add a new section zero before number 1.:

```
.. toctree::
   :numbered:
   
   00.rst
   01.rst
   02.rst
```

But, that seems to be a bit harder than expected... An old version of sphinx (4.x) seems to support `:numbered: 0` and then shows me the first item without a number and then starts correctly at 1, but current versions seems to have fixed this (I guess) bug.

What can I do with sphinx 7.x to start the numbering at zero, or alternatively do not number the zeroth section and start numbering at 1 for file 01.rst?

Edit: `:numbered:` is only implemented as a boolean flag. 0 disabled it and any postive number enables it. Seems like that the old implemetation was indeed a bug. So far, I worked around this by using two toctrees, the first one not numbered with only `00.rst` in. That makes it work for now.